# Глобальные переменные для MVC django

Tags: python, mvc, django

Доброго времени суток.
Вопрос в следующем:
  Есть несколько страниц у которых есть общая менюшка, в менюшку тянутся данные с базы (предполагаю её подключать через include).
  Как лучше передавать переменные в шаблон для этой менюшки? В каждой в рендер передавать "right_menu": _menu(), не комильфо. Может кто подскажет лучшее решение?

```
def _menu(user):
    data = {
        "orders": order.objects.filter(who_orders=user).count(),
        "orders_ok": order.objects.filter(who_orders=user, status=1).count(),
        }
    return data
```

[А вот и ответ](http://djbook.ru/rel1.6/howto/custom-template-tags.html#inclusion-tags). Спасибо [Елене](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/13665/%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

не совсем понятно, что именно имеется в виду, но менюшку имеет смысл делать тэгом. И посмотрите, кстати, есть уже готовые решения, например [django-sitetree](https://github.com/idlesign/django-sitetree)

Comment: Можно еще нужные данные передавать через context processor, если меню глобальная для всего сайта.

Comment: ну так да, в тэг takes_context=True передать можно. Кажется, начинаю понимать, что имел в виду автор :) Действительно, с позиции новичка не очевидно, что меню удобнее делать именно так. В туториалах же описаны вьюхи, да как из вьюх в шаблоны данные передаются, про встроенные тэги тоже написано, про include в том числе, а вот до использования context processor дойти нужно самостоятельно.

Comment: Спасибо за совет, но это немного не то.
По поводу тегов: возможно выход, но не совсем красиво..
Ещё такой вопрос, к примеру хочу узнать в шаблоне где сейчас пользователь, дабы можно было ссылке присвоить класы active или unactive, возможно ли это сделать без фильтров/тегов и patch()?

Comment: тэги — это традиционный вариант :) И да, в самом шаблоне логике не место (по крайней мере по задумке авторов Django), поэтому такое и делается в тэгах. Там можно разобрать context['request'], по результатам добавить к нужному элементу поле, и уже это поле смотреть в шаблоне.

Либо, если уж очень хочется в шаблоне, то можно написать тэг, всего лишь возвращающий context['request'].META['REQUEST_URI'], либо даже фильтр, сравнивающий переданную ему строку с этим значением. То есть, без тэга или фильтра всё равно не обойтись.

Comment: А вот за переменную context отдельное спасибо!) А я всё мучался как в тэге получить request

Comment: А вот почитайте: http://djbook.ru/rel1.6/howto/custom-template-tags.html#simple-tags — всё вполне понятно изложено.

Comment: http://djbook.ru/rel1.6/howto/custom-template-tags.html#inclusion-tags
Вот то, что было нужно) зря не дочитывал документацию до конца